# Find null space (kernel) and image of these linear transformations/maps of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

let $V$ be a vector space of functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
Consider the linear map:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A} : V \to V \mbox{ where } (\mathcal{A}f)(x) = f(x^2)
\end{equation}
and the linear map:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A} : V \to V \mbox{ where } (\mathcal{A}f)(x) = (x+1)f(x)
\end{equation}
I have proven they are in fact linear. I have no trouble determining the null space and image of other maps of functions, however, I couldn't quite get the hang of these.

What I have (in a nutshell):

- (Kernel of the first map):

  Exists of all functions whose value is $0$ whenever $x \geq 0$.
- (Image of the first map):

  All functions which are symmetric in the $y$-axis. Because if we take $x = -a$, then $(\mathcal{A}f)(x) = f(x^2) = f((-a)^2) = f(a^2)$.
- (Kernel of second map):

  All funtions whose value is 0 whenever $x \neq -1$. What value those functions have whenever $x = -1$ does not matter as long as they are defined for this value of $x$.
- (Image of second map):

  In any case the set of functions $\{f(-1) = 0 \mid f \in V \}$ will be in the image space. If the function is not defined in $x = -1$, then the function will still be in the image space whenever the function is defined for some other value of $x$. The image space is therefore the union of the the set $\{f(-1) = 0 \mid f \in V \}$ and all functions that are not defined on $x = -1$ but are defined for some other value of $x$.

Are these foundings correct?

Comment: Looks basically good. I have no idea what you mean by $f$ not defined at ... As $f$ should be total, that is defined everywhere. Your proofs are always little bit short.